# Kafka - Redirect messages from "Topic A" to "Topic B" based on header value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to redirect kafka messages from a topic called "all-topic" to a topic named "**headervalue**-topic" where **headervalue** is the value of a custom header each message has.

At the moment i'm using a custom console application that consumes messages and redirects the messages to the correct topic, but it only process 16 messages per second.

Both kafka and zookeeper are running in a docker container, configured as such :

```
zookeeper:
  image: "wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest"
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"
  environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1

kafka:
  hostname: kafka
  image: "wurstmeister/kafka:latest"
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
  environment:
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
```

What is the best and fastest way to achieve my goal?

I do know about the existence of Kafka Streams, but i'm not familiar with Java so in case you'd like to suggest Kafka Streams a little example would be appreciated :)

Many Thanks!

Comment: And yes, you need to write a Kafka Stream application to achieve this. There are lots of example of Kafka stream app available at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i came up with, using kafka-streams nodejs library :

```
const {KafkaStreams} = require("kafka-streams");
const {nativeConfig: config} = require("./config.js");

const kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(config);
const myConsumerStream = kafkaStreams.getKStream("all-topic");

myConsumerStream
    .mapJSONConvenience()
    .filter((element) => {
        return element.value.type == "Article";
    })
    .tap((element) => {console.log("Got Article")})
    .mapWrapKafkaValue()
    .to("Article-topic", 1, "buffer");

myConsumerStream.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you can't access the header directly through DSL.
You can access it through ProcessorContext using stream processor though and here is a little example I came up with:

```
public class CustomProcessor1 implements Processor<String, String> {
private ProcessorContext context;

@Override
public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext) {
    this.context = processorContext;
}

@Override
public void process(String key, String value) {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    for (Header header : context.headers()) {
            headers.put(header.key(), new String(header.value()));
    }
    String headerValue = headers.get("certainHeader").replace("\"", "");

    if (headerValue.equals("expectedHeaderValue")) {
        context.forward(key, value);
    }
}
```

Above is the processor which will forward messages with certainHeader that matches headerValue to downstream process. This processor will be used when creating the streaming topology like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties props = getProperties();

    final Topology topology = new Topology()
            .addSource("SOURCE", "all.topic")
            .addProcessor("CUSTOM_PROCESSOR_1", CustomProcessor1::new, "SOURCE")
            .addProcessor("CUSTOM_PROCESSOR_2", CustomProcessor2::new, "SOURCE")
            .addSink("SINK1", "headervalue1-topic", "CUSTOM_PROCESSOR_1")
            .addSink("SINK2", "headervalue2-topic", "CUSTOM_PROCESSOR_2");
```